# Rsyslog regular expression

Tags: centos, regular-expression, configuration, rsyslog

I have a lot of incoming `syslog` messages on my `rsyslog` server. It's a `stormshield` that sends different categories of messages (connection, web, alarm, ...)

I can't configure a different facility for each category so I need to use regular expression to split incoming messages in differents files.

All messages are different and have more or less fields in the message, but there is one field `logtype` to identify the category :

```
Syslog message 
Msg = bullshitcontentbullshitcontent logtype:"connection" bullshitcontentbullshitcontent
```

So the question is :

How can I collect the string of the `logtype` field with a POSIX regular expression that is understandable by `rsyslog` and - if you know how - split in different files depending of the value of the `logtype`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late, but it is possible. I dont know how you are getting these logs (a quick search suggested network, maybe), but I've got a similar setup. You can use [rulesets](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/concepts/multi_ruleset.html), to make (funnily enough) new sets of rules that aren't used as default. And in the inbuild scripting language [RainerScript](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/index.html), theres an `re_match` function, that returns true or false.

```
ruleset(name="stormshield") {
    if re_match($msg, "your POSIX ERE regex") then {
        action(type="omfile" file="/your/file/name/here")
        stop
    } else if re_match(...) then { ... }
    else { ... }
}
```

`$msg` is a reference to to current log.

`omfile` is for output module, so if you need databases or anything, theres other options too.

And once you have finished the `if..else if...else` other things can go there. the `stop` is needed to discard the msg once its finished with, otherwise it'll go to other rules too. I think you can add a tilde `~` after the action too for this, but you'll have to check.

How to direct the logs to the ruleset (`bind` to it as the docs say) depends on the source. for network or file sources, theres the `input` function, and [input modules](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/idx_input.html) such as `"imtcp"` and `"imfile"` which have a ruleset parameter. You may have to get extra packages for some of the modules:

```
input(type="imfile" File="/input/file/here.log" Tag="..." Ruleset="ruleset name")
input(type="imtcp" Port="1234" Name="name" Ruleset="ruleset name")
```

and finally if you need to send a particular facility you may be able to use [`call`](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/rainerscript_call.html): `local0.* call rulesetName` (no quotes for the name it seems) for example (choose what needs logging as required)

I think I've got much of this ok. I've just been looking at the conf files so apologies for any errors..